# How to construct a table in IEEE format in latex that covers both the column and goes beyong a page?

Tags: latex, ieee

The Situation
The code if executed could develop a table the covers the entire page in IEEE format but when I try to make the table more than a page longer, it doesn't show the last datas of the code that goes beyond one page.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] % filler text
\begin{table*}
 \caption{CIFAR-10 Confusion Matrix}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{10}{C}c@{}}
\toprule
labels     & airplane & automobile & bird & cat & deer & dog & frog & horse & ship & truck & accuracy \\ 
\midrule
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 

dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\lipsum[2-15] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

I want to find a way to include a table in IEEE format in Latex where it can cover the entire page instead of just half and goes beyond a single page.